# Maven artifacts for neo4j-cypher-dsl newer than 1.9.M04 are missing

Tags: maven, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

Trying to update a project from Spring Data Neo4j version 2.3.1.RELEASE to 3.0.0.RELEASE, but I'm getting maven artifact not found errors on neo4j-cypher-dsl version 2.0.1.

I found this link https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.neo4j/neo4j-cypher-dsl which shows 2.0.1, but clicking that link, then the URL link (http://components.neo4j.org/neo4j-cypher-dsl/2.0.1), I get a 404.

The same is true for every other version of neo4j-cypher-dsl greater than version 1.9.M04.

Any thoughts on how to resolve?

-Chris

Comment: The link immediately below that one is valid and contains the correct package. I can successfully compile a 3.0.0.RELEASE SDN project, check that you properly cleanup everything when moving from 2.3.1, even try with a fresh new project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

neo4j-cypher-dsl is released to http://m2.neo4j.org. To use that in your maven build, add http://m2.neo4j.org/content/repositories/releases/ to your list of repositories.

E.g. for 2.0.1 use http://m2.neo4j.org/content/repositories/releases/org/neo4j/neo4j-cypher-dsl/2.0.1/neo4j-cypher-dsl-2.0.1.jar

Comment: That worked; thanks!  I had http://m2.neo4j.org configured as a remote repository, but not the full path to the /releases folder (using Artifactory).

Comment: Don't forget to add it to Nexus repository group if you're using it (such as myself).